# Como fazer o número do registro do aluno da conta logada ficar na tabela da publicação feita?

Tags: java, mysql

Estou fazendo um projeto de rating de uma "faculdade", tenho a classe publicação e nela o método:

```
public String NovaPublicacao(Connection conn){

      String sqlInserir = "INSERT INTO Publicacao (Assunto, Conteudo, RA) VALUES (?, ?, (SELECT RA from Alunos where Nome = " + aluno.getNome() + "))";

      try (PreparedStatement stm = conn.prepareStatement(sqlInserir);) {
            stm.setString(1, getAssunto());
            stm.setString(2, getConteudo());
            stm.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                conn.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                System.out.print(e1.getStackTrace());
            }
        }

      return getConteudo().toString();
    }
```

Como fazer RA do aluno logado, que fez a publicação, ir para a tabela de publicação que tem relação de 1:n com o aluno, ou seja, um aluno faz várias publicações.

Comment: Quando o usuário loga você armazena os dados em sessão? Se sim, basta pegar o RA que está na sessão. Caso o RA não esteja, acrescente esta informação quando o aluno se logar.

Comment: aluno.setRA(Integer.parseInt(txtRa.getText()));
         aluno.setNome(txtNome2.getText());
         aluno.setNome_usuario(txtLogin2.getText());
         aluno.setSenha(txtSenha2.getText());    isso seria armazenar os dados em sessão?

Comment: Não! Neste caso você apenas está populando o objeto, Vc está usando JSF? Se for JSF seria assim instanciando uma session `SessionContext session = SessionContext.getInstance();` armazenando os dados numa session = `session.setAttribute("nomeUsuario", u.getNomeUsuario());`- Recuperando um atributo da session  `String nome = (String) session.getAttribute('nomeUsuario);`.

Comment: Não, a interface foi feita manualmente, não uso framework :(

Comment: Sem problema. Pesquise sobre session e procure a implementação que se encaixa em sua arquitetura.

Answer (score 0):

Nao sei se entendi bem sua pergunta, mas o que precisa é simplesmente, tirar esse select do seu codigo de insert e acrescentar mais uma linha:

```
stm.setString(1, getAssunto());
stm.setString(2, getConteudo());
stm.setString(3, getRA());
stm.execute();
```

Quando o aluno se logar vc insere o RA do mesmo com um setRA(ra).